# Can I swap HashMap keys and values to other?

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm new to Java and what I want to do is to swap all the keys and values of `HashMap` (**hm**) to `HashMap` (**hm2**) and vice versa. I didn't find any solution for this. Is it possible?

```
import java.util.*;

class HashMapSwap{
public static void main(String args[]){
    HashMap<Integer, String> hm = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    HashMap<Integer, String> hm2 = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    
    hm.put(3, "Mobile");
    hm.put(11, "Tab");
    
    hm2.put(4, "PC");
    hm2.put(1, "Laptop");
    
    Map tmp = new HashMap(hm);
    tmp.keySet().removeAll(hm2.keySet());
    hm2.putAll(tmp);

    for(Map.Entry en:hm2.entrySet()){
        System.out.println(en.getKey() + " " + en.getValue());
    }
}
}
```

**O/P :**

> 1 Laptop
>
> 3 Mobile
>
> 4 PC
>
> 11 Tab

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// store first map in (new) temporary map
HashMap<Integer, String> tempMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>(hm);

// clear first map and store pairs of hm2
hm.clear();
hm.putAll(hm2);

// clear second map and store pairs of tempMap
hm2.clear();
hm2.putAll(tempMap);

// EDIT (hint from Palcente)
// optional: null the tempMap afterwards
tempMap = null;
```

Comment: null the tempMap afterwards or keep it on the stack

Answer (score 2):

tmp can be used to swap references as below.

```
        HashMap<Integer, String> hm = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        HashMap<Integer, String> hm2 = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

        hm.put(3, "Mobile");
        hm.put(11, "Tab");

        hm2.put(4, "PC");
        hm2.put(1, "Laptop");

        HashMap tmp = new HashMap();
        tmp = hm;
        hm = hm2;
        hm2 = tmp;

        for(Map.Entry en:hm.entrySet()){
            System.out.println(en.getKey() + " " + en.getValue());
        }
        for(Map.Entry en:hm2.entrySet()){
            System.out.println(en.getKey() + " " + en.getValue());
        }
```

Comment: Thanks there, it works.. But is it recommended to swap the unique key values?

Comment: Not sure about your question here, but IMO this is better in case of time complexity.